# How to set money format in PhpSpreadSheet?

Tags: php, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

I'm using PHPSpreadSheet and I want to set money format for a cell.
In PHPExcel you can do this by using the following lines...

```
$this->phpExcelObject->getActiveSheet()
     ->getStyle('D4')
     ->getNumberFormat()
     ->setFormatCode(\PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_CURRENCY_USD_SIMPLE);
```

I tried to this in PHPSpreadSheet, this is what i did...

```
$this->spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()
     ->getStyle('D4')
     ->getNumberFormat()
     ->setFormatCode('$ #,##0.00');
```

But it doesn't work.
Any ideas? or am I doing it wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -7, accepted):

I couldn't do it with PHPSpreadSheet. In case someone runs with the same problem, this is what I did (not a proper solution but it's something).

I created a function to return the value with the money symbol.

```
public function formatValueMoney($number){
  $val = number_format($number,2,".",",");
  $setVal = '$'.$val;

  return $setVal;
}

$int = formatValueMoney(34567898765);
echo $int;
```

and this : **$34,567,898,765.00** is the result. i just added this in the cell.

Answer (score 28):

I was able to do the following with PHPSpreadsheet:

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle($thisCol)
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode(PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\NumberFormat::FORMAT_CURRENCY_USD_SIMPLE);
```

The format code for `FORMAT_CURRENCY_USD_SIMPLE` `==` `'"$"#,##0.00_-'`

Comment: What will be the format code if i wanted XXXXXXXX to be transformed to X,XX,XX,XXX.00.  instead of XX,XXX,XXX.00 ?

Answer (score 10):

You can use this, if you are working with [applyFromArray](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/recipes/#valid-array-keys-for-style-applyfromarray):

```
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

$sheet->getStyle($thisCol)->applyFromArray(

    'numberFormat' => [
        'formatCode' => \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\NumberFormat::FORMAT_CURRENCY_EUR
    ]
);
```

Otherwise use it like this:

```
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->getStyle($thisCol)
      ->getNumberFormat()
      ->setFormatCode(PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\NumberFormat::FORMAT_CURRENCY_EUR);
```

Use `FORMAT_CURRENCY_USD` for dollar

> **Note**: You can also add **_SIMPLE** e.g. FORMAT_CURRENCY_EUR_SIMPLE if you like to show two decimal point values e.g. 12,62 € instead of 12 €

Checkout the class `\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\NumberFormat` to find out all possible values.

The class is stored in *vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\NumberFormat.php*

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<?php

use \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\DataType;

$xls   = new Spreadsheet();
$sheet = $xls->getActiveSheet();

$sheet->getStyle('D4')->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('###,###,###.##');
$sheet->setCellValueExplicit('D4', $your_value, DataType::TYPE_NUMERIC);
```